# HTML z-index not working as expected - element position issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with an input element whose position is determined by the normal flow of the page (i.e. its position is **NOT** explicitly defined as part of the element definition).

Then, I have other elements (divs) that are created programmatically with fixed position, and should appear behind the input element whenever there is an overlap between them.

I tried assigning to the input element a ridiculously high z-index (100001, while the programmatically elements have a z-index < 1000) but the input element still is shown *BEHIND* the others.

I found some posts suggesting that the input element should also be positioned as the other elements, but this could have negative impact on the general layout of the page.

What can I try next?

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index is intended for elements positioned as `absolute`, `relative` and `fixed`.

Try setting your input `position: relative`, then you z-index should work.

```
#myInput {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100001;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Geoman. I marked your answer as it was the first. I did solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` only applies to positioned elements, so you need to position it.

Set it to `position: relative` if you want to position it without moving it or taking it out of normal flow.

Comment: Thank you Quentin. I upvoted your answer as correct, but (to be fair) marked Geoman's as it was the first answer.